# wxPython: Passing parameters within GUI class

Tags: python-2.7, parameters, wxpython

I am trying to port a CLI based program into a GUI to make it more user friendly.  I have got the basics of wxPython, but theres one issue which has stumped me.

I have defined a dialog box which takes a parameter allowing me to create dynamic dialog boxes:

```
    def infoDialog(self,event,message):
        dialog = wx.MessageDialog(None, message, 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        dialog.ShowModal()
```

I have a main subroutine within the class which generates all the GUI elements:

```
    def initGUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
```

If I call the info dialog within initGUI like this:

```
    pidButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Open...', pos=(540,445), size=(60,20))
    pidButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.questionDialog(event,"Hi!"))
```

Then I get this error:

> ```
> pidButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.questionDialog(event,"Hi!"))
> ```
>
> NameError: global name 'event' is not defined

**Yet this works if I call it from a subroutine that isnt initGUI().  How do I go about fixing this?**

I appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind an event handler to the button event, and inside that handler call any actions you would like to happen.

Notice that when you bind you pass a reference to to the handler without calling it ie no () other wise you bind the result of calling the handler. The handler must accept one argument.

```
import wx
from wx.lib import sized_controls


class MainFrame(sized_controls.SizedFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetTitle('MainFrame')
        pane = self.GetContentsPane()
        button = wx.Button(pane, label='open')
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_open_button)

    def on_open_button(self, event):
        self.infoDialog("Hi!")

    def infoDialog(self, message):
        dialog = wx.MessageDialog(
            None, message, 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        dialog.ShowModal()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wxapp = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot.  I have one final question, how would I go about calling infoDiaglog from outside the class?  Such as:

def warning():
    if...
       infoDialog("Warning!")

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, I can now call dialog boxes!

I didn't initialise the class properly.  Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

As the exception tells you you do not have 'event' defined at that point, but I also don't see qeustionDialog defined, so I think you need to make these change.

Change:

```
def infoDialog(self,event,message):
```

to:

```
def infoDialog(self, message):
```

and:

```
pidButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.questionDialog(event,"Hi!"))
```

to:

```
pidButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.infoDialog)
```

Comment: Thank you Werner for your reply,  I pasted the code for the wrong subroutine, but in fact they're both the same your suggestion has fixed my problem.

The problem now is that the dialog box opens when I run the program and doesn't pop up when I press the button!

Comment: Yoriz's answer made me realize that the 'Bind' was incorrect in my answer, which I explains your problem that it opens when you run it, i.e. when it hits the wrong 'Bind' line, but doesn't open when you press the button.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help. It all works now